# Displaying text using php echo with innerhtml inside a data-filter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have attempted to inject php instead of text as innerhtml using 'onclick'  This script appears in the 'head' of my website.  I have a data-filter to display images under categories. 'onclick' the images are displayed.  Underneath the images the php as text should appear - a heading for the category and description underneath.  If left as straight innerhtml this all works.  It is the php echo that doesn't.  I really would like this to work so that the heading and description can be managed from the CMS (database).
[1](http://bootstraplovers.com/assan-kit-v3.7/bootstrap4/website-templates/classic-template/html/folio-mosaic-full.html)[this is an example of the type of image display] http://bootstraplovers.com/assan-kit-v3.7/bootstrap4/website-templates/classic-template/html/folio-mosaic-full.html)<

```
    <!-- script for product category and description -->
    <script> 

            function clearText(){ //clears all TEXT when ALL link clicked               
            document.getElementById('productCategoryName').innerHTML="";                
            document.getElementById('productDescription').innerHTML="";         

            }
            function getDetails_Propagation(){ //get details for Propagation products when PROPAGATION link clicked 
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_categoryID=4";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    extract($row);
                ?>          
            document.getElementById('productCategoryName').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['product_categoryName']; ?>";             
            document.getElementById('productDescription').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>";           
                <?php
                    } //end of while
                ?>
            }
            function getDetails_Ventilation(){ //get details for Ventilation products when VENTILATION link clicked 
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_categoryID=7";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    extract($row);
                ?>                  
            document.getElementById('productCategoryName').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['product_categoryName']; ?>";             
            document.getElementById('productDescription').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>";       
                <?php
                    } //end of while
                ?>
            }
            function getDetails_Heaters(){ //get details for Heaters products when HEATERS link clicked             
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_categoryID=8";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    extract($row);
                ?>                  
            document.getElementById('productCategoryName').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['product_categoryName']; ?>";             
            document.getElementById('productDescription').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>";       
                <?php
                    } //end of while
                ?>

            }               
            function getDetails_Screens(){ //get details for Screens products when SCREENS link clicked             
            <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_categoryID=6";
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    extract($row);
                ?>                  
            document.getElementById('productCategoryName').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['product_categoryName']; ?>";             
            document.getElementById('productDescription').innerHTML="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>";       
                <?php
                    } //end of while
                ?>
            }               
    </script>
</head>
<body>


        <ul class="filter list-inline">
            <li><a class="active" href="#" data-filter="*" onclick="clearText()">Show All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography" onclick="getDetails_Propagation()">Propagation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".illustration" onclick="getDetails_Ventilation()">Ventilation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding" onclick="getDetails_Heaters()">Heaters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web-design" onclick="getDetails_Screens()">Screens</a></li>
        </ul>           


        <div class="portfolio-box iso-call col-5-no-space">

            <div class="project-post branding">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Heaters_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="heaters">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Heaters_1.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post web-design">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/screen1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screens">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/screen1.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post web-design">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/screen2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screens">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/screen2.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post web-design">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/screen3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screens">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/screen3.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post branding">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Heaters_2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="heaters">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Heaters_2.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post END ROW ONE-->

            <div class="project-post illustration">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_extractorFan1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_extractorFan1.jpg"" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post  branding">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Heaters_3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="heaters">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Heaters_3.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post web-design">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/screen4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screens">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/screen4.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->   
            <div class="project-post web-design">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/screen5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screens">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/screen5.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post web-design">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/screen6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/screen6.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post END ROW TWO-->

            <div class="project-post photography">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/propagation_armMistController.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/propagation_armMistController.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post photography">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/propagation_thermostat.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="propagation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/propagation_thermostat.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post photography">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/propagation_armMistController2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="propagation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/propagation_armMistController2.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post photography">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/propagation_soilwarmingCable.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="propagation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/propagation_soilwarmingCable.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post illustration">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_extractorFan2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventiliation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_extractorFan2.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post END ROW THREE-->

            <div class="project-post photography">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/propagation_soilwarmingCable2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="propagation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/propagation_soilwarmingCable2.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post illustration ">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_airInlet1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_airInlet1.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post photography">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/propagation_thermostat2.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="propagation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/propagation_thermostat2.gif" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post photography">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/propagation_thermostat3.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="propagation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/propagation_thermostat3.gif" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post illustration">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_airInlet2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_airInlet2.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post END ROW FOUR-->

            <div class="project-post illustration">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_airInlet3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_airInlet3.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post illustration ">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_extractorFan3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_extractorFan3.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post illustration">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_stirrerFan1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_stirrerFan1.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post illustration">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_stirrerFan2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_stirrerFan2.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post-->
            <div class="project-post illustration">
                <div class="img-icon">
                    <img src="images/products/Ventilation_stirrerFan3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="ventilation">
                    <div class="img-icon-overlay">
                        <p>
                            <a href="images/products/Ventilation_stirrerFan3.jpg" class="show-image"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sliders"></i></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--img-icon-->
            </div><!--project post END ROW FIVE-->

        </div>   
        </div> <!--end portfolio-box-->
        <!-- product category details -->
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="blog-post">   
                    <h2 id="productCategoryName"></h2> <!-- function in head -->
                    <p id="productDescription"></p> <!-- function in head -->           
                </div><!--blog post--> 
            </div><!--end col-->
            </div><!--row for blog post-->  
      </div> <!--full width-->   
    </div> <!--end container--> 



       </body>
```

Comment: Please don't do this. This is the core reason people hate working with PHP. Please first prepare variables (use arrays of values if necessary), then use the prepared values. Goal: Separate view from logic as much as possible.

Comment: `php` is server-side source code so this will be executed before loading the page elements. `javascript` is a client-side language and will not run `php` after loading the page.

Comment: @MovedBiscuit 73 . since this is about javascript not replacing the content, can you also please paste the HTML output of the script in your case? OR the database dump so we can run it with the data you use?
ALSO: the extract function doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: My work around was to display a text slideshow and onclick PHP echo works.   I was taught that PHP is a very robust language and can be displayed anywhere.  Anyway solved my own dilemma!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to write comment try this

```
 <?php echo "<script>document.getElementById('productCategoryName').innerHTML=". $row['product_categoryName']."</script>" ?>
```

i hope this code for learning only and not for actual production.

i hope this help you !